# What solid foods to give a picky toddler to make her satisfied?

Tags: toddler, eating, solids

I'm a teen mom and my 19-month-old baby girl is so picky she barely eats baby foods. Everytime she sleeps during the day or night when she wakes up all she wants is milk. I’ll have to wait when she’s hungry later to give her real food which sometimes she doesn’t eat. I need help and suggestions on what to give her as solids that she might like as a baby please...

Comment: Does she eat at the table with you, and the same foods?

Comment: Sometimes yes she eats the same food as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transitioned my son off "baby foods" by giving him the baby cereal mixed with vegitable beef soup (concentrate). He got a variety of (soft) vegitables with well cooked meat. If your daughter is full from solid foods, she is less likely to be dependant on milk.
 I would like to add, when she wakes and you think she only wants milk, she might really want to be held so she can wake up slowly. Distract her with a pacifier, bottle of water, or some milk that's thinned with water, even a saltine, while calming her. Then make her something that will fill her up. Some of it should be finger foods that she can explore and eat on her own. You will (both) get through this.

Answer (score 1):

You might not like my answer, no-one does, but it works! instead of asking her to eat "offer" her to eat, put some great food around her, keep it there all the time, and let her worry about her hunger herself...

I would put food on the table, if it's something new I would say aloud,

"it's delicious, would you like some?",

she: "no",

me: "oh! who cares! that means more for me!" (but in our heart we care nonetheless)

and after some time (minutes or seconds) she would start eating (if she doesn't straight-away hate that food, which is usually not the case)... AhL

if you think she's young enough to understand your language, eat infront of her with great pleasure...

curiosity works!!! :)

PS: never ever even say that "you're wasting food", children are not good with their motor skills so they waste food while eating, never discourage them and never laugh at them!!! you can ruin their confidence in an instance!

Answer (score 0):

It's say she's normal, not picky. By 19 months she should be on regular foods, cut up. You try some of that baby food and you'll see why no one likes baby food ( except Apple sauce and sweet potato).

Comment: Even with regular food she’s being picky too I’ve stopped giving her baby food a while ago.

Comment: You may want to update your question to indicate that. Also quantify how much she does eat.